# neo4j sum rows with identical fields

Tags: neo4j, sum, nosql, aggregate

```
MATCH (b:Book)<-[ol:ORDERLINE]-()
UNWIND b.genre as genre
RETURN genre, ol.amount
```

gives this result

```
│"genre"   │"ol.amount"│
│"Genre-1" │1          
│"Genre-3" │1
│"Genre-1" │2  
│"Genre-10"│2          
│"Genre-1" │5          
│"Genre-10"│5
```

and I want this output

```
│"genre"   │"ol.amount"
│"Genre-1" │8          
│"Genre-3" │1
│"Genre-10"│7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aggregation functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) to get the result you need:

```
MATCH (b:Book)<-[ol:ORDERLINE]-()
UNWIND b.genre as genre
RETURN genre, sum(ol.amount) as `ol.amount`
```

Comment: @DavidAStumpf That depends on whether the genre property is a string or a list of strings. UNWIND was used in the original question, so I assumed the property was a list of string genres.